# Least Squares Solution for a Matrix System with Diagonal Matrix Constraint

Tags: convex-optimization, diagonalization, least-squares

> Let's say I have the following equation
>       $$AX=B$$
>   where $A$ is a $8\times 3$ matrix (known), $X$ is a $3\times3$ "diagonal" matrix which represents the coefficients (unknown) and $B$ is a $8\times 3$ matrix (known).

Whenever I solve for $X$ using least squares $X= (A^TA)^{-1} A^T B$, I get a square matrix which is not diagonal.

Any idea how can I force least square solution matrix to be diagonal?

Comment: Mathematical formulae look better in $\LaTeX$. Here (http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a quick tutorial.

Comment: Related to [Solve Least Squares (Frobenius Norm) Problem with Diagonal Matrix Constraint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2421545).

Answer (score 2):

The solution can be written as
$$\eqalign{
X &= {\rm Diag}\Big((I\odot A^TA)^{-1}\,{\rm diag}(A^TB)\Big) \\
}$$
where $(\odot)$ denotes the elementwise/Hadamard product, Diag() creates a diagonal matrix from a vector argument, and diag() returns the main diagonal of its matrix argument as a vector.

This result is derived as follow.

---

The independent variable in this problem is the vector $x,\,$ from which a diagonal matrix is defined *strictly* for notational convenience.
$$\eqalign{
X &= {\rm Diag}(x) \quad\implies\quad  x = {\rm diag}(X) \\
}$$
Given the matrices $(A,B),\,$ the problem is to minimize the function 
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \tfrac{1}{2}\,\|AX-B\|_F^2 \\
  &= \tfrac{1}{2}\,(AX-B):(AX-B) \\
}$$
where the colon denotes the trace/Frobenius product, i.e. 
$$A:B={\rm Tr}\big(A^TB\big)$$
Calculate the gradient of the function.
$$\eqalign{
d\phi
  &= (AX-B):A\,dX \\
  &= \big(A^TAX-A^TB\big):dX \\
  &= \big(A^TAX-A^TB\big):{\rm Diag}(dx) \\
  &= {\rm diag}\big(A^TAX-A^TB\big):dx \\
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x} &= {\rm diag}\big(A^TAX-A^TB\big) \\
}$$
Set the gradient to zero and solve for the optimal vector.
$$\eqalign{
{\rm diag}(A^TAX\,I) &= {\rm diag}(A^TB) \\
(I\odot A^TA)\,x &= {\rm diag}(A^TB) \\
x &= (I\odot A^TA)^{-1}\,{\rm diag}(A^TB) \\
X &= {\rm Diag}\Big((I\odot A^TA)^{-1}\,{\rm diag}(A^TB)\Big) \\
}$$
The preceding makes use of the Hadamard-Diag identity, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
{\rm diag}\Big(A\;{\rm Diag}(x)\;B\Big) &= \big(B^T\odot A\big)\,x \\
}$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is the thing. If $X=diag(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ then the elements of first row of $AX$, i.e. $a_{11}x_1, a_{12}x_2, a_{13}x_3$, are equal to $b_{11}$, $b_{12}$ and $b_{13}$ respectively. Hence $x_1=b_{11}/a_{11}$ and $x_2=b_{12}/a_{12}$...further, the second row gives then $x_1=b_{21}/a_{21}$,...and so forth until the 8th row. So in order for $X$ to be a diagonal it must be that the first column of $B$ is a multiple of the first column of $A$, the second column of $B$ a multiple of the second column of $A$ and likewise for the third (that is $b_{.1}=x_1a_{.1}$, $b_{.2}=x_2a_{.2}$,...). I guess your known matrices do not satisfy that.

I guess what you want to do is to minimize $(AX-B)'(AX-B)$ with respect to $X$ under the necessary side conditions (being 'off diagonal elements of $X$ are zero')

Edit: actually, $X$ being diagonal gives you three equations of the form $b_{.i}=a_{.i}x_i$ for each column $i$. The least square solution is
$$x_i=(a_{.i}'a_{.i})^{-1}a_{.i}'b_{.i} $$ for each $i$.
Now, solving this way means you are treating the columns as separate equations. If they are related by correlated error terms, google for SUR (seemingly unrelated) equations, to find efficient estimators...

Answer (score 0):

Decouple your equations to force diagonalization. A simpler problem demonstrates the basics.

Instead of solving
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a_{11} & a_{12} \\
 a_{21} & a_{22} \\
 a_{31} & a_{32}
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 x_{11} & x_{12} \\
 x_{21} & x_{22} 
\end{array}
\right)
%
=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 b_{11} & b_{12} \\
 b_{21} & b_{22} \\
 b_{31} & b_{32}
\end{array}
\right)
$$
solve instead
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a_{11} & a_{12} \\
 a_{21} & a_{22} \\
 a_{31} & a_{32}
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 x_{1} & 0 \\
 0 & x_{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 b_{11} & b_{12} \\
 b_{21} & b_{22} \\
 b_{31} & b_{32}
\end{array}
\right).
$$
This is two separate problems for $k=1,2$:
$$
\left(
  \begin{array}{c}
    a_{1k} \\
    a_{2k} \\
    a_{3k}
  \end{array}
\right)
 x_{k} 
=
\left(
  \begin{array}{c}
    b_{1k} \\
    b_{2k} \\
    b_{3k}
  \end{array}
\right)
$$
The pseudoinverse of a vector $v$ is $\frac{v^{\mathrm{*}}}{\lVert v \rVert}$. For example
$$
\left(
  \begin{array}{c}
    a_{1k} \\
    a_{2k} \\
    a_{3k}
  \end{array}
\right)^{\dagger}
=
\frac{
\left( 
\begin{array}{ccc}
  a_{1k} & a_{2k} & a_{3k}
\end{array}
\right)
}{\lVert a_{k} \rVert}.
$$
The least squares point solution is
$$
  x_{k} = a_{k}^{\dagger} b_{k} = \frac{ \sum_{j=1}^{3}a_{jk}b_{jk} } {\sqrt{ \sum_{j=1}^{3}a_{jk}a_{jk} }}.
$$

Comment: I think the Pseudo Inverse has $ { \left\| {a}_{j} \right\|}_{2}^{2} $ in its denominator. As you need $ {a}_{j}^{\dagger} {a}_{j} $ to be equal to $ 1 $. The solution is $ {x}_{k} = \frac{ {a}_{k}^{T} {b}_{k} }{ { \left\| {a}_{k} \right\|}_{2}^{2} } $.