# Matrix Linear Least Squares Problem with Diagonal Matrix Constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, least-squares, svd

How could one solve the following least-squares problem with [Frobenius Norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm) and diagonal matrix constraint?

$$\hat{S} := \arg \min_{S} \left\| Y - XUSV^T \right\|_{F}^{2}$$

where the $S$ is a diagonal matrix and $U,V$ are column-orthogonal matrix. Is there any fast algorithm?

Comment: What are; $X$, $F$ and $T$? Please update your question.

Comment: @unseen_rider X is the variable matrix, T denotes the transpose operation, F denotes the Frobenius norm

Comment: I think is possible to find a closed form solution to this

Comment: Not only closed form, it boils down to just a regularized linear least squares system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### The Problem

Stating the problem in more general form:

$$ \arg \min_{S} f \left( S \right) = \arg \min_{S} \frac{1}{2} \left\| A S {B}^{T} - C \right\|_{F}^{2} $$

The derivative is given by:

$$ \frac{d}{d S} \frac{1}{2} \left\| A S {B}^{T} - C \right\|_{F}^{2} = A^{T} \left( A S {B}^{T} - C \right) B $$

#### Solution to General Form

The derivative vanishes at:

$$ \hat{S} = \left( {A}^{T} A \right)^{-1} {A}^{T} C B \left( {B}^{T} B \right)^{-1} $$

#### Solution with Diagonal Matrix

The set of diagonal matrices $ \mathcal{D} = \left\{ D \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} \mid D = \operatorname{diag} \left( D \right) \right\} $ is a convex set (Easy to prove by definition as any linear combination of diagonal matrices is diagonal).

Moreover, the projection of a given matrix $ Y \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} $ is easy:

$$ X = \operatorname{Proj}_{\mathcal{D}} \left( Y \right) = \operatorname{diag} \left( Y \right) $$

Namely, just zeroing all off diagonal elements of $ Y $.

Hence one could solve the above problem by Project Gradient Descent by projecting the solution of the iteration onto the set of diagonal matrices.

The Algorithms will be:

$$
\begin{align*}
{S}^{k + 1} & = {S}^{k} - \alpha A^{T} \left( A {S}^{k} {B}^{T} - C \right) B \\
{S}^{k + 2} & = \operatorname{Proj}_{\mathcal{D}} \left( {S}^{k + 1} \right)\\
\end{align*}
$$

The code:

```
mAA     = mA.' * mA;
mBB     = mB.' * mB;
mAyb    = mA.' * mC * mB;

mS          = mAA \ (mA.' * mC * mB) / mBB; %<! Initialization by the Least Squares Solution
vS          = diag(mS);
mS          = diag(vS);
vObjVal(1)  = hObjFun(vS);

for ii = 2:numIterations

    mG = (mAA * mS * mBB) - mAyb;
    mS = mS - (stepSize * mG);

    % Projection Step
    vS          = diag(mS);
    mS          = diag(vS);

    vObjVal(ii) = hObjFun(vS);
end
```

[image]

#### Solution with Diagonal Structure

The problem can be written as:

$$ \arg \min_{s} f \left( s  \right) = \arg \min_{s} \frac{1}{2} \left\| A \operatorname{diag} \left( s \right) {B}^{T} - C \right\|_{F}^{2} = \arg \min_{s} \frac{1}{2} \left\| \sum_{i} {s}_{i} {a}_{i} {b}_{i}^{T} - C \right\|_{F}^{2} $$

Where $ {a}_{i} $ and $ {b}_{i} $ are the $ i $ -th column of $ A $ and $ B $ respectively. The term $ {s}_{i} $ is the $ i $ -th element of the vector $ s $.

The derivative is given by:

$$ \frac{d}{d {s}_{j}} f \left( s \right) = {a}_{j}^{T} \left( \sum_{i} {s}_{i} {a}_{i} {b}_{i}^{T} - C \right) {b}_{j} $$

**Note to Readers**: If you know how vectorize this structure, namely write the derivative where the output is a vector of the same size as $ s $ please add it.

By vanishing it or using Gradient Descent one could find the optimal solution.

The code:

```
mS          = mAA \ (mA.' * mC * mB) / mBB; %<! Initialization by the Least Squares Solution
vS          = diag(mS);
vObjVal(1)  = hObjFun(vS);

vG = zeros([numColsA, 1]);

for ii = 2:numIterations

    for jj = 1:numColsA
        vG(jj) = mA(:, jj).' * ((mA * diag(vS) * mB.') - mC) * mB(:, jj);
    end

    vS = vS - (stepSize * vG);

    vObjVal(ii) = hObjFun(vS);
end
```

[image]

**Remark**
The direct solution can be achieved by:

$$ {s}_{j} = \frac{ {a}_{j}^{T} C {b}_{j} - {a}_{j}^{T} \left( \sum_{i \neq j} {s}_{i} {a}_{i} {b}_{i}^{T} - C \right) {b}_{j} }{ { \left\| {a}_{j} \right\| }_{2}^{2} { \left\| {b}_{j} \right\| }_{2}^{2} } $$

#### Summary

Both methods works and converge to the optimal value (Validated against CVX) as the problem above are Convex.

The full MATLAB code with CVX validation is available in my [StackExchnage Mathematics Q2421545 GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes/tree/master/Mathematics/Q2421545).

Comment: Is the $\hat{S}$ a diagonal matrix ?

Comment: Could I select the diagonal elements of $\hat{S}$ ? So it can ensure that $\tilde{S}$, the diagonal matrix estimation, is what I want.

Comment: I updated my solution to fully support Diagonal Matrices.

Comment: CVX is a bit overkill for this one, but it definitely works.

Comment: I didn't solve with CVX. I used it to validate my solution.

Comment: Can you explain or solve the same cost function with the constraint that $\mathbf{S}$ is a lower-triangular matrix?

Comment: @Maxtron, Open a new question and we'll give it a try. Just remember to link it here in a comment.

Comment: @Royi I posted it here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2876283/imposing-lower-triangular-matrix-as-an-equality-constraint-in-optimization but you can try solving it for the same cost function as above.

Comment: @Royi I understand that the projection step involves using `tril` command in MATLAB, but my question is can we exploit the structure of the matrix to make it converge faster?

Answer (score 3):

The closed-form solution to this problem is
$$S = {\rm Diag}\bigg(\Big(I\odot U^TX^TXU\Big)^{-1}{\rm diag}\Big(U^TX^TYV\Big)\bigg) \\
$$
which was derived as follows.

---

For typing convenience, define the matrices 
$$\eqalign{
S &= {\rm Diag}(s) \\
A &= XUSV^T-Y \\
}$$
Write the problem in terms of these new variables, then calculate its gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \|A\|^2_F = A:A \\
d\phi &= 2A:dA \\
 &= 2A:XU\,dS\,V^T \\
 &= 2U^TX^TAV:dS \\
 &= 2U^TX^TAV:{\rm Diag}(ds) \\
 &= 2\,{\rm diag}\Big(U^TX^TAV\Big):ds \\
 &= 2\,{\rm diag}\Big(U^TX^T(XUSV^T-Y)V\Big):ds \\
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial s} 
 &= 2\,{\rm diag}\Big(U^TX^T(XUSV^T-Y)V\Big) \\
}$$
Set the gradient to zero and solve for the optimal vector.
$$\eqalign{
{\rm diag}\Big(U^TX^TYV\Big)
 &= {\rm diag}\Big(U^TX^TXU\;{\rm Diag}(s)\;V^TV\Big) \\
 &= \Big(V^TV\odot U^TX^TXU\Big)\,s \\
 &= \Big(I\odot U^TX^TXU\Big)\,s \\
s &= \Big(I\odot U^TX^TXU\Big)^{-1}{\rm diag}\Big(U^TX^TYV\Big) \\
S &= {\rm Diag}\bigg(\Big(I\odot U^TX^TXU\Big)^{-1}{\rm diag}\Big(U^TX^TYV\Big)\bigg) \\
}$$
In some of the steps above, the symbol $(\odot)$ denotes the elementwise/Hadamard product and $(:)$ denotes the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{ A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)}$$
Finally, the ${\rm diag}()$ function returns the main diagonal of a matrix as a column vector, while the ${\rm Diag}()$ function creates a diagonal matrix from its vector argument.

Answer (score 1):

Vectorize $S$, express matrix multiplication by $X,U$ from left and $V^T$ from right with Kronecker products. Now you have a linear least squares problem in which you can add the extra term $\left\| D \text{vec}(S) \right\|_F^2$, where you make $D$ to be a diagonal weight matrix with large positive values corresponding to  off-diagonal elements in $S$. This will regularize away any non-diagonal solution $\hat S$.

---

**EDIT:**

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Matrix_equations), you can use the following relation to build your objective term:

$${\bf AXB = C} \Leftrightarrow ( {\bf B^T \otimes A} )\text{vec}({\bf X}) =\text{vec}({\bf C})$$

Then to build the *regularizing term* - enforcing a diagonal matrix, just add $+\lambda\|{\bf D}\text{vec}({\bf X})\|_F^2$, where $$\cases{D_{ii} = \cases{0,&index $i$ corresponds to diagonal element in X\\1,&index $i$ corresponds to non-diagonal element in X}\\D_{ij} = 0, i\neq j}$$

Comment: Could you show what you mean with more details? Any idea how to vactorize the gradient in my answer for a closed form solution?

Comment: @Royi : I edited to add more details.

Comment: Any idea how to derive closed form solution from my above derivative of the Diagonal Structure? How to vaectorize the gradient calculation?

Answer (score 0):

$U S V^T$ with $S$ diagonal is an SVD, so let's put the problem into SVD form:

$\qquad \text{argmin}_\sigma \| Y - \sum \sigma_i (X u_i) \otimes v_i \|$

Denote $W_i \equiv (X u_i) \otimes v_i$.
These $W_i$ are orthogonal, because the $v_i$ are.
Treating $Y$ and $W_i$ as 1d vectors $y$ and $w_i$
(Frobenius dot product), we want

$\qquad \text{argmin}_\sigma \| y - \sum \sigma_i w_i \|$ with $w_i$ orthogonal:

$\qquad \sigma_i  = {{ y \cdot w_i} \over {w_i \cdot w_i }}$ .