# Matrix least-squares problem with lower triangular matrix constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, least-squares, quadratic-programming

Given the matrices $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ and $\mathbf{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times N}$,

\begin{align}
\arg \min_{\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times M}} \| \mathbf{A} - \mathbf{X} \mathbf{B} \|_\mathrm{F}
\end{align}

where $\|\cdot\|_\mathrm{F}$ is the Frobenius norm operator. The above problem can be rewritten as

\begin{align}
\arg \min_{\mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{X})} \mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{X})^T (\mathbf{B}\mathbf{B}^T \otimes \mathbf{I}) \mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{X}) - 2 \mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{A} \mathbf{B}^T)^T \mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{X}).
\end{align}

where $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product. The above optimization can be solved easily as it is a quadratic program with no constraints. Suppose, we are given prior information that $\mathbf{X}$ is a lower-triangular matrix, how do I impose it as an equality constraint in the form of $\mathbf{C} \mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{X}) = \mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{Y})$ where $\mathbf{C} \in \mathbb{R}^{MN \times MN}$ and $\mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{Y})$ is the vectorized lower-triangular entries of $\mathbf{X}$? In other words, how to determine the entries of matrix $\mathbf{C}$?

Note that I can use CVX in MATLAB to solve this but when the dimensions of the matrices are large, then CVX takes a lot of time for computing.

Comment: Indeed, CVX is not the right tool for this problem. This is actually just a least-squares problem, really. The right thing to do is _not_ to impose an equality constraint to enforce the lower-triangular nature of it. Effectively, what you want to do is just eliminate the rows of the "vectorized" least-squares problem that correspond to the upper triangle of X.

Comment: How do I do that? Is $\mathbf{C}$ a diagonal matrix with ones on all those positions which represents the lower-triangular matrix indices? Then, $\mathbf{C}$ may not be full rank.

Comment: Another bottle neck with this approach is the storage of large Kronecker product. Do you have some useful tricks that might help me overcome this?

Comment: Yeah, that part I understand. I think there should be a solution here. I need to think about it more

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why won't @MichaelGrant 's response work? You really have several least squares problems on your hands with objectives of the form $$||a^T_k[1:k] - x_k^TB||$$ where $a_k^T[1:k]\in\mathbf{R}^{k}$ is the first $k$ components of row $k$ in $A$, $x^T_k\in\mathbf{R}^{k}$ is the $k$th row of $X$

Comment: Interesting. Can you explain me how Frobenius norm is equivalent to solving $N$ least squares problem? If you can point me to the proof, that would be helpful.

Comment: See page 233: https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/vmls/vmls.pdf

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can we solve using the same approach if the optimization problem was $\arg \min_{\mathbf{X}} || \mathbf{C}^T (\mathbf{A} - \mathbf{X} \mathbf{B}) ||_\mathrm{F}$ where $\mathbf{C}$ is non-invertible. Note, we are talking about very large matrices.

Comment: @Maxtron is right, but it's not _just_ N separate least squares problems. By exploiting the matrix structure you can do this with just one matrix factorization.

Comment: @MichaelGrant Can you explain your comment elaborately?

Comment: I think what @MichaelGrant was saying is that solving the vector least squares problem $||Ax-b_1||$ "costs" about the same as solving several least squares problems of the form $||Ax-b_k||$ because behind the scenes these are usually done using a "factor-solve" procedure and the "factor" step dominates the floating point operation count. So you can reuse that rather than doing $N$ totally independent problems.

Comment: @Maxtron regarding the second question, off the top of my head I'm not sure. There may be an obvious closed form solution (looks a little like weighted least squares if you squint at it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_least_squares ). If the matrix is sufficiently large maybe you'd be best off calculating the gradients and doing an iterative approach?

Comment: @Casey Many thanks for explaining Grant's comment. It helps. As far as the second comment goes, the problem is weighted least squares if $\mathbf{C}$ is full rank. When it is not, there's no simplified approach to solve this problem for large matrices. Perhaps, exploiting the structure of $\mathbf{B}$ can be useful.

Comment: @Maxtron please un-accept my answer; it is _not_ correct.

Comment: Yes normal linear least squares is good enough and quadratic and/or convex programming would be a bit overkill. But you may need to practice some in how to construct the matrices.

Comment: @Casey's link is to the book [Stephen Boyd, Lieven Vandenberghe - Introduction to
Applied Linear Algebra](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/vmls/vmls.pdf) Page 233 (Decomposing Matrix Least Squares with Frobenius Norm to several Vector Least squares.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is given by:

$$ \arg \min_{X \in \mathcal{T} } \frac{1}{2} {\left\| X B - A \right\|}_{F}^{2} $$

Where $ \mathcal{T} $ is the set of Lower Triangular Matrices.

The set $ \mathcal{T} $ is a Convex Set.
Moreover, the orthogonal projection onto the set of a given matrix $ Y \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} $ is easy:

$$ X = \operatorname{Proj}_{\mathcal{T}} \left( Y \right) = \operatorname{tril} \left( Y \right) $$

Namely, zeroing all elements above the main diagonal of $ Y $.

By utilizing the Projected Gradient Descent it is easy to solve this problem:

$$
\begin{align*}
{X}^{k + 1} & = {X}^{k} - \alpha \left( X B {B}^{T} - A {B}^{T} \right) \\
{X}^{k + 2} & = \operatorname{Proj}_{\mathcal{T}} \left( {X}^{k + 1} \right)\\
\end{align*}
$$

[image]

The full MATLAB code with CVX validation is available in my [StackExchnage Mathematics Q2876283 GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes/tree/master/Mathematics/Q2876283).

The solution is very similar to the solution in [Q2421545 - Solve Least Squares (Frobenius Norm) Problem with Diagonal Matrix Constraint](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2421784/33).

**Remark**
I think you can also get a closed form solution for each element in $ X $ if you go through deriving the derivative with respect to each element $ X $.
Another approach would be developing the Linear Operator which operates on $ \frac{ \left( n - 1 \right) n }{2} $ elements and creates an $ n \times n $ Triangular Matrix.

Comment: Can a lower-triangular matrix constraint be imposed by $\ell_0$ norm operator? Then, maybe we can accelerate this approach. However, $\ell_0$ norm only constraints that $K$ atoms are non-zero, but does not specify which positions of those $K$ atoms are zeros.

Comment: @Maxtron, Much easier approach would be imposing zeros on the elements which are not in the lower triangle. It is a linear constraint and target the objective directly hence easier to do (Also keeps the problem Convex). You can either do that by the projection above or use an operator as I wrote in my remark.

Comment: The problem with the current approach is that it takes a lot of time to converge when you are dealing with large matrices. Is there a way we can accelerate projected gradient descent? Note that both the cost function and constraints are convex. Perhaps, algorithm like FISTA can be used?

Comment: @Maxtron, In any problem which is convex and the iteration is Gradient Descent / Proximal Gradient Descent (Generalization of the Projected Gradient Descent) you may use acceleration method such as FISTA. Pay attention that $ B {B}^{T} $ and $ A {B}^{T} $ should be pre calculated.

Comment: @Maxtron, You may have a look how I used FISTA like acceleration in Projected Gradient Descent (As above) in my answer to [How to Solve Linear Least Squares Problem with Box Constraints](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3558242/33).

Comment: Yes, I am aware of FISTA algorithm and have used it to implement the above problem in my code :)