# Optimization problem involving a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, least-squares

I would like to find the solution $D = \text{diag}(d_1,\dots,d_n)$ to the following minimization problem,
$$
\min_D || A - B D C ||_F^2
$$
where $|| \cdot ||_F$ is the Frobenious norm, $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, and $C \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ are given matrices. My approach so far is:
\begin{align}
\min_D || A - B D C ||_F^2 &= \min_D || \text{vec}(A - B D C) ||^2 \\
&= \min_D || \text{vec}(A) - \text{vec}(B D C) ||^2 \\
&= \min_D || \text{vec}(A) - (C^T \otimes B) \text{vec}(D) ||^2
\end{align}
This is now a standard least squares problem, except it would solve for all elements of the matrix D. Is there a clever way to enforce the constraint that $D$ is diagonal and construct a least squares problem only for the diagonal elements of $D$?

Comment: How about $\mathrm{vec}(D) = S [d_1, d_2, \cdots, d_n, 0, \cdots, 0]^\mathsf{T}$ (easily to find $S$)?

Comment: It seems this question has been answered already here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3494125. I am still trying to understand the answer, but it seems to be correct for the case that $C$ is orthogonal.